# Facebook Like View not working

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-like

In my app i'm trying to include the facebook like button, but it's working only with app administrator and developer accounts.
When i click the like button with a non-developer account, the like dialog isn't shown, but the fragment onActivityResult() is called.

Comment: Actually the app is in development testing, i haven't published it on the Play Store yet

Comment: Have you marked it as Live in the Facebook app dashboard

Comment: Yes, i have. Any ideas?